# How to connect to a remote MYSQL database using real IP in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, backend

I have configured the connection in Nodejs file as shown below.
The problem happens when trying to connect to the remote database on a server

```
module.exports = {
    host: '234.32432.32432',//this is example IP not a real one.
    user: 'bob',
    password: '*****',
    database: '****',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
}
```

Comment: what's the error you get? please note, usually mysql is configured to accept local connections only, that might be the problem

Comment: this is the error: 
parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 234.32432.32432:3306
[0]       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
[0]     errno: -4078,
[0]     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[0]     syscall: 'connect',
[0]     address: '234.32432.32432',
[0]     port: 3306,
[0]     fatal: true
[0]   },

Comment: if mysql is configured to accept local connections only, then how can i connect to remote database on specific server please?

Answer (score 0):

You need configure your mysql to allow remote connection.
Edit file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
You will Find a line looks like this:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Change it to this:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

After saving, restart your mysql.

**Notice:**

> **In certain versions of MySQL the bind-address directive may not be in the mysqld.cnf file by default.**

Comment: I already did that but didn't work for me

Comment: there is much  more firewall, also the user grants